# Android minimum version when publishing on market

Tags: android, publishing, google-play

I've already asked Google support about this and they were no help ...

In my manifest I have

uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"

which corresponds to version 2.3.3 however when I publish the app to the market it says that the minimum version required is 2.3.7 and uses that in the filter.

How do I tell the market to use 2.3.3 as the minimum version ??

Thanks.

Comment: What does your AndroidManfest.xml look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your manifest filter entries (or) API used is compatible of 2.3.7 than 2.3.3 (I suspect you might upgraded to 2.3.7) which prevents using 2.3.3 even though you use min-sdk 10.

see this comment from [documentation](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3.3.html)

o use APIs introduced in Android 2.3.3 in your application, you need compile the application against the Android library that is provided in the Android 2.3.3 SDK platform.

Comment: Thanks. The API version I used was 2.3.7. I had to recompile it using 2.3.3

Answer (score 1):

2.3.7 is the latest revision of Gingerbread_MR1. I would recommend switching to SDK version 9 if supporting 2.3.3 is really that important.